# What is the song played in Operation 11: Fallen Angel Rina?

Tags: music, cool-devices

The song that Rina sings in the opening/ending -- is it an existing pop song in Japan or a song created just for the series?

Comment: This is a bit vague. Is there one specific song? Is this an opening or ending song, or just one sung during the film? I have never seen it, but I find your question a bit vague.

Comment: The opening and ending. It looks like it's the theme song.

Comment: Would you please move this questions somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "Fallen Angel's Love". The music is by Shinobu and written by Masamichi Kaneko.

[Sources: I checked the English version of the ending credits.]

Answer (score 4):

> The opening and ending. It looks like it's the theme song

The Opening song, written by Reiji Kitazato, is called "Girls and horny sluts", it's probably most definitely not an existing pop song in Japan. While Reiji Kitazato does music for other (non-hentai) series, like Gankutsuou, this is probably written specifically for this show.

Comment: While it's good, I mean the song Rina actually sing in front of concert

Comment: Not the theme song of cool device in general. It's theme song of all.